# How to fix Error: capacitor.config.json does not exist, did you setup capacitor in your project root? when adding electron with capacitor in ionic?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, npm, electron, capacitor

I have a ionic-react project a I'm trying to add electron support using capacitor by doing:

```
ionic start blah tabs --type=react --capacitor
npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron
```

but it throws this error:

```
Error: capacitor.config.json does not exist, did you setup capacitor in your project root?
    at Object.n [as doAdd] (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:6:1016)
    at C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:12:363
    at Object.g [as runTask] (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:2:1888)
    at i (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:12:311)
    at C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:12:718
    at Object.parcelRequire.Focm../common (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:12:915)
    at f (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:1:468)
    at parcelRequire.FoEN (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:1:771)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron\dist\cap-scripts.js:1:1023)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
```

I am changing the env variable INIT_CWD as `set INIT_CWD=C:\Users\My-Name\blah\node_modules\@capacitor-community\electron` following https://github.com/capacitor-community/electron/issues/76 but nothing seems to be working. The project just had capacitor.config.ts so I added the capacitor.config.json myself:

```
{
  "appId": "io.ionic.starter",
  "appName": "blah",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 0
    }
  },
  "cordova": {}
}
```

I've updated versions of node,npm and ionic kindly help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your ionic project root, you should have installed *npm install @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli* with the --capacitor option, please try the following:

1. install *npm install @capacitor-community/electron*
2. run *npx cap init*
3. *ionic build*
4. *npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron*
5. *npx cap open @capacitor-community/electron*

Answer (score 0):

Mine was all due to my projects parent folder having a space in its name.